# Bundle install and update cannot find and install jQuery-rails 2.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I'm trying to learn Rails from [this website](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/beginning).
I'm on Windows so I used the recommended [Rails-Installer](http://railsinstaller.org). I need to have `jquery-rails` gem version 2.0.0 for the tutorial so in my gem file I have those:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
end


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.2'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.0'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
```

As it can be seen, I have `gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.0'` line in `Gemfile`. However, when I run `bundle update` or `bundle install` I get this error:

```
bbundle install could not find gem ' jquery-rails (= 2.0.0) x96-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your gemfile.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

gem jquery-rails version '2.0.0' was yanked from rubygems
http://rubygems.org/gems/jquery-rails/versions/2.0.0

replace with

```
gem "jquery-rails", "~> 2.0.1"
```

and be happy